# Apache index page in json/plain text

Tags: apache

I need to write a script that would connect to a server, get a list of files and then download some of them.

The file listing is on the Apache's default index page which looks like this:

[image: mod_autoindex]

While this html page is not hard to parse, it would still be great if one could get this list in a more machine-friendly format, e.g. JSON or plain text.

I don't have any control over the server, so the best I can try is to add some headers/query string parameters/... (let's assume that all options are set to defaults on the server side). Is there any way to do this?

I tried sending `Accept` header with `application/json` and `text/plain` but it still returns html page. The best way I found so far is to append `?F=0` query string to the url - it still returns the html but without fancy icons and styles.

Answer (score 1):

The feature is provided by the [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_autoindex.html) module. The [supported query string arguments](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_autoindex.html#query) only include these values:

> ```
> F=0 formats the listing as a simple list (not FancyIndexed)
> F=1 formats the listing as a FancyIndexed list
> F=2 formats the listing as an HTMLTable FancyIndexed list
> ```

... which, in the end, are nothing but variations of HTML.

So that's all you can do if you have no control over the server.